# Removing white space on a table in python

Tags: python, plotly, jupyter, plotly-python, quarto

[image]

I want to remove the whitespace between the table and the figure number which does not look clean on the quarto website. This is a plotly table

here is the code that I'm trying to run

````
```{python}
#| echo: false
#| label: fig-wealthy
#| fig-cap: "Wealthy Indicators"

values = [
    [
        'Income Ratio', 
        '% Children in Poverty', 
        'Unemployment Rate'
    ], #1st col
    [
        'Ratio of household income at the 80th percentile to income at the 20th percentile',
        'Percentage of children (under age 18) living in poverty',
        'Percentage of population ages 16+ who are unemployed'
    ]
]


fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Table(
  columnorder = [1,2],
  columnwidth = [25,60],
  header = dict(
    values = [
        ['<b>Indicator</b>'],
        ['<b>Description</b>']
    ],
    line_color='darkslategray',
    fill_color=['rgb(241, 241, 241)', 'rgb(241, 241, 241)'],
    align=['center','center'],
    font=dict(color='rgb(22,74,88)', size=12),
    height=20
  ),
  cells=dict(
    values=values,
    line_color='darkslategray',
    fill=dict(color=['white', 'white']),
    align=['left', 'left'],
    font=dict(color='black', size=12),
    height=30)
    )

])
fig.show()
```
````

Comment: Why the [tag:r] and [tag:rstudio] tags? If you want workarounds in the R language, then I suggest you should be specific about requesting that. Regardless, I don't see any connection with the RStudio IDE itself (not any language running within it), so the second tag is incorrect.

Comment: I'm using this in quarto hence the rstudio tags

Comment: Unless you can show that this works outside of RStudio and fails within it, the tag is not appropriate. (Sorry, I'm not a jupyter guru nor how to fix this.)

Comment: What is `go`? Can you provide a minimal reproducible example of a complete quarto file? (with information such as intended output format)

Comment: what do you mean by go?

Comment: Like the `go` in `go.Figure`? But my main emphasis is on providing a minimal reproducible and complete example using which people can reproduce the problem you are facing! :)